# How to connect row from table1 with data in table2 where all data in table2 has id of row from table1

Tags: mysql, row

```
//Table 1
$table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS questions (
id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
quesion TEXT NOT NULL,
user VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
question TEXT NOT NULL,
answer TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)";

//Table 2
$table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS answers (
id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
answer TEXT NOT NULL,
datum TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)";
```

I have two forms. One for inserting question and other for inserting answers. It's working. But i have a problem. It is normal that for one question you have few answers, but right now when i submit answer, and try to add second answer for first question, it overwrite me first answer. 
//this code do that

```
$sql="UPDATE questions SET answer='$_POST[answer]' WHERE id='$_POST[id]'";
```

I now - it is obviously that every inserted answer do to the table 'questions', but i need to insert answers into table 'answers' and every answer to be connected for his question from table 'question'

So, resume - user come to the site, see The question, answer on it and leave, after come second user and give answer for same question and also leave.. 
How to make it work. I've trying with some foreign keys, but nothing..

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra field, lets say for ex. `QuestionId` to your answser table.
In your insert SQL u provide the QuestionId to your answser insert statement.

Then u can select all your answers for one question with :

```
SELECT * FROM answser WHERE QuestionId=$qId
```

Comment: Hi. I try this, and it's giving me only the answers for the first question. But there is a lot of questions, and when i give the answer for ex. Question2 doesn't show anything in output. How can i make that for every Question have answers bellow that question? Do you know?

Comment: So I need to echo that bellow <tr>? And it give me some error / unexpected '{'. I try to change, remove, add some curly braces, but nothing.

Comment: Forgot a `)` at line 9 (http://pastebin.com/8BSsc5hg updated link). The code is just a mere illustration of how to query the required data tho. U'll need to adjust to your needs